# the usage of "as"

Tags: word-usage, as

- > My first job after college **was as** a teacher in Cotulla, Texas, in a
  >   small Mexican-American school.

(My first job after college **was *a job* as** a teacher in Cotulla.)

- > His main scientific contribution **was as** a statesman of science.

(His main scientific contribution **was *a contribution* as** a statesman of science.)

- > His primary identity **was as** a priest.

(His primary identity **was *an identity* as** a priest.)

I've read through the different dictionaries but couldn't find a satisfying explanation of this kind usage of "as".
Can I understand these sentences as in the brackets?

Comment: "*used to say what job, duty, use, or appearance someone or something has*" [Definition 2 here.](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/as_1) Does this help? If not, please explain what you specifically don't understand.

Comment: In the role of.

Comment: @Catija  Then what is the difference between the following sentences.  1)"His primary identity was as a priest."    2)"His primary identity was a priest."

Comment: It sounds better with "as". Without "as" it makes me think that it's formatted like: *His job was: a priest." or that there's no need to say it was his "job": "He was a priest."

Comment: The more I keep reading the sentence the more I get the feeling of it. I think I've got it. Thank you, both of you.

Answer (score -3):

I would say as, in this context, means while in that particular position or suty. For example, your first sentence means... My first job was being a teacher....
The second one means ... Scientific contribution made when he was a scientist or while doing scientific things